# SQL Combining Where and Select

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a string of data, `House Electricity - 1234`, which i have stored in an SQL database.

I am attempting to restrict the string down to the four digit number code at the end, but when the data is put into the database it needs to have the descriptive terms first.

The environment I am working in lets me run **SQL queries**, however there is a catch.

It must begin with `SELECT Nominal_Code FROM Housing WHERE`

I can't change the order of these.

I have tried putting in a RIGHT ('House Electricity - 1234', 4) in afterwards, but it doesn't seem to do anything.

Is there any solution to this?

*Edit for clarity.*

The Column is called Nominal_Code

The Table is called Housing

The solution must start with `SELECT Nominal_Code FROM Housing WHERE` - as the software I am using (Docuware) requires it in that exact format to begin with.

The goal is to get `House Electricity - 1234` to replace itself with 1234.

Comment: Please read & act on [mcve]. What is your input? What exactly should the output look like? What exact query did you write? What column has strings like that? Why do you expect that row to be picked? The `where` gives that. The `select` clause should ask for the `right` `4` characters of the value of what column? If you want that value in column `Nominal_Code` then you need `Housing` to have column with that value. Or does "Nominal_code" represent code you have to write?? Please clearly explain.

Comment: Change the software you are using.

Comment: I think I have amended it as you asked there. Is there anything else that is missing that you would need?
In regards to changing software,  If that was an option I would, but unfortunately it is not. If it isn't possible I'll have to look into other solutions within the software.

Answer (score 0):

Too long for a comment...

Seems fine to me:

```
SELECT 'a123', RIGHT('a123',3);
+------+-----------------+
| a123 | RIGHT('a123',3) |
+------+-----------------+
| a123 | 123             |
+------+-----------------+
```

Comment: This is similar to what I tried, but I get the error that a boolean is expected, because the RIGHT has to come after the WHERE.

Comment: In which case, see philipxy's comment above.